# Xamarin.Android Recycler View prevent duplicated items being added

Tags: android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, speech-to-text

I am using a Recycler View in my app and the user can add items to the list via speech to text or manually via text.

For the speech to text I have set it up so that list items are seperate by the word and.

For example fish and chips adds the items "fish" and "chips" to the recycler view.

But if someone says fish and chips and chips, how can I prevent chips being added twice?

I'm thinking I need to add something in the OnActivityResults method?

The same as if the item is already in the list how can I prevent it being added again?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the code for us? Have you trieed to foreach the items list and match the new item `chips`?

Comment: Hi sorry yes I will put code on later when home. Currently I only have foreach to add each item to the list

Comment: When you add each item to the list, you could do the match first. It would help to avoid adding duplicate item.

Comment: Are you able to give an example of how to check for matches?

Comment: Could you provide the code about how to add the items into the list? I would do the change on that.